# How to find all files with filenames starting with a character "x" followed by 1 digit in current directory

Tags: linux, unix

Below command will show all the files that begins with "x". Im trying to figure out an option on how to display only one digit after the 'x'.

```
$ find ~ -type f -iname 'x*'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find ~ -type f -iname 'x[0-9]'
```

`[0-9]` will match a single digit. Omitting `*` means the name has to match exactly, not just as a prefix.

Answer (score 0):

Barmar was close, but no sigars :-)

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname 'x[0-9]'
```

With following explanation:

```
. is the current directory (~ is the home directory of the current user)
-maxdepth 1 means: find within that directory (don't look into subdirectories)
-iname 'x[0-9]' means: the name must be like "x" (case insensitive), followed by a number 0..9
```